# Streaming big table using scalikejdbc

Tags: postgresql, scala, scalikejdbc

I have a query that returns a big chunk of data, I would like to stream this data from postgres to scala using a fetch size. My code looks something like this

```
  override def getFilteredData(filters: Seq[Filter]): StreamReadySQL[myObject] =  {
      sql"""  QUERY
        """.stripMargin
           .fetchSize(2000)
           .map(MyObject(_))
           .iterator()
  }
```

And in some other class I am calling it like that

```
  val productPublisher: DatabasePublisher[RuleData] = {
    DB readOnlyStream {
      repositories.productRepository.getFilteredData(trigger.filters)
    }
  }

  Source.fromPublisher(publisher).mapAsync(Parallelism) { batch =>
    //do something
    Future.successful(().asRight[ApplicationError])
  }.runWith(Sink.head[Either[ApplicationError, Unit]])
```

Using this code, the above source will only return the last n fetched entries, How do get an iterator from the stream where I can iterate over all the data?

Comment: How does the argument "filters" for the #getFilteredData method work? Also, if you could reproduce the situation by modifying tests for scalikejdbc-stream module, that'll be helpful to distinguish what the problem is. https://github.com/scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc/blob/master/scalikejdbc-streams/src/test/scala/somewhere/DatabasePublisherSpec.scala

Comment: Filters is case class defined in our project, it controls the where clause in the executed query